# environment variable 'HOME' value on windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task, environment-variables

I have a ruby script running in the context of a scheduled task (windows server 2012r2), running as user "Administrator".

Here is the sequence of events which recreates this issue:

1. Create an AWS AMI, which includes ruby script (which just logs `ENV['HOME']` to file, for example) plus windows task to run it every minute
2. Launch a new instance from the AMI, wait for it to do its thing
3. Log in (over RDP) to the instance

One can see that *before* the login, `ENV['HOME']` is evaluating to "C:\Users\Default", whereas *afterwards* it is evaluating to "C:\Users\Administrator".

The task history says that the task was run as user "SYSTEM" in both cases.

The desired (expected) behaviour is that `ENV['HOME']` will *always* evaluate to "...\Administrator", regardless of whether a login has occurred or not.

How can this be made so?

Comment: Possibly related to http://superuser.com/a/527727/77211 ?

Comment: Could be the answer: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2968540